# Cucumber reading data from a 3 column table?

Tags: ruby, automation, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, bdd

I am trying to read data from a three-column inline-data table in cucumber.

Feature File:

```
Then  I should see grades,exteriors, interiors and engines available:
  |grades            |exteriors         |  engine |
  |xdata-id-Elegance |xdata-id-NH-788p  |  12345  |
  |                  |xdata-id-NH737M   |         |
  |                  |xdata-id-NH731P   |         |
  |                  |xdata-id-R-539P   |         |
```

Step_definitions:

```
 Then(/^I should see grades,exteriors, interiors and engines available:$/) do |table|
      data = table.rows_hash
      puts data['exteriors']
    end
```

Which gives me the error only 2 rows allowed.

Does anyone know another way I can access, all three columns using the table object?

Answer (score 3):

Worked for me in a more simpler way, with a three column data table as:

```
  Scenario: I am able to select a date range

    Given I am on the rejections tracker page as a superuser
    Then the date range filters work as expected
      | dateFrom   | dateTo     | variance    |
      | 12/05/2014 | null       | lesser than |
      | null       | 12/07/2014 | lesser than |
      | null       | null       | equal to    |
```

This works for me:

```
    Then(/^the date range filters work as expected$/) do |table|

      data = table.hashes
      date_from = []
      date_to = []
      variance = []

      data.each do |row|
        row.each do |key, value|
          if key.eql? "dateFrom"
            date_from << value
          elsif key.eql? "dateTo"
            date_to << value
          elsif key.eql? "variance"
            variance << value
          end
        end
      end

      puts date_from
      puts date_to
      puts variance
   end
```

Output:

```
  ["12/05/2014", "null", "null"]
  ["null", "12/07/2014", "null"]
  ["lesser than", "lesser than", "equal to"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`raw`](http://cukes.info/api/cucumber/ruby/yardoc/Cucumber/Ast/Table.html#raw-instance_method) to get the table and then use Ruby to manipulate it to a form that you want.

For example, the following shows how to take the table and then convert it to a hash where the keys are the column headers and the values are an array of the values in that column.

```
Then(/^I should see grades,exteriors, interiors and engines available:$/) do |table|
    data = table.transpose.raw.inject({}) do |hash, column| 
        column.reject!(&:empty?)
        hash[column.shift] = column
        hash    
    end

    p data['grades']
    #=> ["xdata-id-Elegance"]
    p data['exteriors']
    #=> ["xdata-id-NH-788p", "xdata-id-NH737M", "xdata-id-NH731P", "xdata-id-R-539P"]
    p data['engine']
    #=> ["12345"]
end
```

Comment: When i add `|table|` to my matcher, I get "Your block takes 1 argument, but the Regexp matched 0 arguments". What needs to change in the feature file for this to work (aside from adding a data table)? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have used the table in a slightly different way.

the "table.hashes" breaks the table rows into arrays, which makes it easy to acces as such.

so we can access the first line like this:

```
puts data[0]
```

which will result in:
{"grades"=>"xdata-id-Elegance", "exteriors"=>"xdata-id-NH-788p", "engine"=>"12345"}

it is then possible to iterate through the objects and print all of them with an ".each", as follows:

```
data.each do |row|
puts row
end
```

which will basically print all the values from your table grouped into arrays (which are your lines). So a bunch of the result aforementioned.

Now there is also the possibility of accessing the key directly which is what you want in the first place, just do as follows:

```
data.each do |row|
puts row["exteriors"]
end
```

Which will print only the values in that column.

Answer (score 0):

The `rows_hash` method is for a particular type of table. Specifically, it's for a table that has two columns, with the headings in the left column. For example:

```
|grades   |xdata-id-Elegance|
|exteriors|xdata-id-NH-788p |
|engine   |12345            |
```

However, your data is in more than one row, so you're using the right type of table.

You could use the regular `hashes` method instead, which will bring back an array of hashes, then extract the data you need from that. For example:

```
Then(/^I should see grades,exteriors, interiors and engines available:$/) do |table|
  data = table.hashes

  exteriors = []

  data.each do |row|
    row.each do |key, value|
      exteriors << value if key == 'exteriors'
    end
  end

  puts exteriors
end
```

This code creates an empty array called `exteriors` and then iterates over each value in the `data` array, which is in turn a hash that corresponds to a non header row in your original table. Each of these hashes represents the values of one of the rows in your table, using the headings as keys.

For each non header row in your table, it then iterates through the hash and populates the `exteriors` array with data.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited tables in the feature file and it gave the below error.
[image]

**Solution:** I just removed the line where it is giving an error and added it again.